# How to interpert this decision tree?

Tags: weka

I am using Weka (for the first time). After loading my data into Explorer I calculated a classifier model with a RandomTree. In the output I got the following:

```
RandomTree
==========

center_letter < 0
|   center_letter < 0 : A (462/0)
|   center_letter >= 0
|   |   next_letter < 0.06
|   |   |   first_letter < 0.05
|   |   |   |   center_letter < 0
|   |   |   |   |   next_letter < 0.05
|   |   |   |   |   |   first_letter < 0.03 : A (3/0)
|   |   |   |   |   |   first_letter >= 0.03 : B (1/0)
|   |   |   |   |   next_letter >= 0.05 : B (2/0)
|   |   |   |   center_letter >= 0 : A (21/0)
|   |   |   first_letter >= 0.05 : B (5/0)
|   |   next_letter >= 0.06 : B (20/0)
center_letter >= 0
... so on
```

What I understand from this doesn't make any sense:
In the first statement it will enter that node if value of "center_letter" is negative (I have no negative values in my data!). Then it checks the same thing again and reports class A (this happened for 462 values?). But then it goes into a branch where "center_letter" is non-negative which is impossible and still finds values in the inner conditions.

What is the proper way to read this tree as what I read doesn't make any sense? A link to an explanation would be great as I can't find one.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for RandomTree? Is there any particular reason you chose this classifier?

Comment: I have. Since posting this I did further research and moved to a different classifier but I still could not understand how to read the result of this classifier.

Answer (score 2):

> tie your eyes on the dashes like this:

```
center_letter < 0
|
center_letter >= 0
```

> They are like traditional branching < ie right and left then:

```
center_letter < 0 : A (462/0)
```

> is a leaf ie stops then dashes continue with:

```
center_letter >= 0
```

> which has two childs:

```
next_letter < 0.06
|
next_letter >= 0.06 : B (20/0)   this is leaf and stops the navigation
```

> then continue with `next_letter < 0.06`
>   and so on..

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense to have a center_letter >=0 inside the center_letter<0 node

Comment: This answer is correct. `RandomTree` doesn't necessarily generate trees that make complete sense, because it's... random. It is intended to be used as a weak learner in ensemble methods, not a classifier in its own right.